# importing a development version of a package from a specific directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to load a development version of a popular Library into my project. Obviously they will have the same package name and therefore cannot co-exist without disambiguation.

My understanding of python module management doesn't go beyond site-packages, the module search path and standard import statements.

My code begins with the following imports:

```
from IPython.frontend.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
from IPython.frontend.qt.embedded_kernelmanager import QtEmbeddedKernelManager
from IPython.frontend.qt.kernelmanager import QtKernelManager
from IPython.lib import guisupport
```

How do I get the IPython symbol to point to a user supplied directory ?

Answer (score 2):

Add that directory to the beginning of the `PYTHONPATH`. You can do this either by setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or by doing something like the following before the imports:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/dev/IPython/dir")
```

Another option is to use the `virtualenv` package to create an environment that gives you sandboxed control over what Python packages are installed.

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install path/to/IPython/dev/package
(venv)$ python some_script.py
```

Comment: but what prevents the interpreter picking up the stable version of ipython from the site-packages directory ?

Comment: Python searches the directories in order along the set of path entries. Adding things to the *beginning* of that list means they'll be searched before things later in the list - hence why you add your development directories at the *beginning*, so they're searched *before* site-packages.